# .net core modelstate is valid even with null required fields

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, modelstate

I have this model:

```
public class FieldMapViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceName = "RangeErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))] public int FeedId { get; set; }
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceName = "RangeErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))] public int FieldId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources)), StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLengthErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))] public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the **Path** is required and the **FieldId** and **FeedId** have a range of 1 to `int.MaxValue`.
So, in my controller, this line should return a **BadRequest**

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);
```

But it isn't.
The model I have passed looks like this:

[image]

The **ModelState** should fail for both **FieldId** and **Path** in this case.
Here is the full code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a new fieldMap
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fieldMap">The fieldMap</param>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(FieldMap), StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync(FieldMapViewModel fieldMap)
{
    if (fieldMap == null) return BadRequest();
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

    var request = ModelFactory.Create(fieldMap);

    _fieldMapService.Create(request);
    await _fieldMapService.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Created(nameof(Get), new Sxp.Web.ActionResult<FieldMap>(request, string.Format(Resources.EntityCreated, "fieldMap")));
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it isn't being picked up?

Comment: If you *do* pass values for those fields in the request, are they properly populated when you inspect the object in the controller?

Comment: yes they are, you can see in the image above I have passed some of the fields (FeedId and Id)

Comment: Ok, I was just checking because I can't see the routing information from your example, and "Id" is one of the constraints usually set up in the default route. Could you add the json or XML of the object you are posting to the endpoint?

Comment: @r3plica did you get your answer?